# insertHtml on IPad inserts empty content control

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I was trying to insert html into the office365 word document and using `insertHtml` method. `insertHtml` inserts an empty content control (shows placeholder instead of my html).

A problem can be reproduced on iPad iOS 11.3 browsers Safari and Chrome.  Native word application on the iPad and other devices (office365 word and native word) are inserting correctly.

Example of the code:

```
 Word.run(async context => {
  const currentRange = context.document.getSelection();
  const control = currentRange.insertContentControl();
  control.insertHtml(
    '<b>Insert any text to test</b>',
    Word.InsertLocation.replace,
  );
  await context.sync().catch(console.error);
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Kindly take a look at my answer and give me feedback before the grace period ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "can be reproduced on iPad iOS 11.3 browsers Safari and Chrome" -- what about Chrome on the desktop or Mac?  If it's always on Word Online, it might well just be a bug with the Word Online implementation of the `insertContentControl` API.  If so, if you haven't already, I'd suggest you file a bug on https://github.com/officedev/office-js/issues

At its face value, the code you wrote seems correct enough. If you want to make it a tad better, you'd be better off sticking the "`.catch`" on the outside of the Word.run.  It doesn't make a difference in your particular case here, since you're calling `context.sync()` on the last line of your batch anyway, but there could be cases where it does.  So as a best-practice, protect your whole `.run` with the catch, rather than just the `sync`.

So: it might be a platform bug.  If so, please file it at the link above.

Comment: Tested on Linux, Windows, Mac different browsers - works correctly. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning some value.

```
Word.run(async context => {
  const currentRange = context.document.getSelection();
  const control = currentRange.insertContentControl();
  control.insertHtml(
    '<b>Insert any text to test</b>',
    Word.InsertLocation.replace,
  );
  await context.sync().catch(console.error);
  return false;
})
```

Comment: As I see on the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/word-add-ins-reference-overview the function should return a promise, since parent is a deferred object.

Comment: `and return a promise to indicate task completion`, to handle async callback. It's not related to the problem. Thank you for making the effort.